# GUI framework for a virtual table (2D)

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a task that probably tons of systems can fulfill. I am looking for a system that combines performance (i.e., responsiveness on standard pc hardware) and ease of programming.

Idea:
A virtual table with notes and photos on it that the user can manipulate (others will do the same, all sync'd over the Internet, but that part is covered). The result should look beautiful: no borders, no windows, as little control elements (e.g., for rotating) as possible.

Requirements:

- The programming language is Java
- The table is 2D (a rectangle with wooden texture)
- Objects are 2D
- The whole table with all objects is zoomable
- Objects can be grouped and ungrouped
- Objects can be resized, rotated, and moved around
- System fonts are supported (i.e., text can be rotated, streched, etc.)
- Images can be partially transparent (full alpha channel support not required)

I would have used Android (which seems perfect for the task), unfortunately, the target systems are PCs and there doesn't seem to be any PC ports for the Android UI (emulation is not what I am looking for).

I am greatful for any input, especially from people who have done something similar or know such projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a project that would take a Java professional hundreds of hours to complete.

Still reading?

Your GUI choices are:

- Java Swing
- Java SwingFX
- Apache Pivot

These GUI choices are listed in order of the amount of help you could expect to get on Stack Overflow.

Pick one, do a Google search, and start reading.  Expect to spend about two months becoming proficient in one of the GUI's.

Next, get familiar with the [model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) architecture.

Next, start working on your model.

This should keep you busy for 3 or 4 months.  If you have any specific questions, that you can't find the answer with a Google search, feel free to post them on Stack Overflow,